# Automating CSV Uploads into Einstein Analytics with Wave DatasetUtils

Tags: java, automation, einstein-analytics, csv, commandline

According to this [Trailblazer Community Post](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?emkind=chatterPostNotification&emtm=1521171041401&fId=0D53A00003SuFvO&fromEmail=1&g=0F9300000009MBP&OpenCommentForEdit=1&s1ext=0&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&s1uid=0053000000Betjf), the [Wave DatasetUtils](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils) tool can be used to automate csv uploads into Einstein Analytics (the user lists this option alongside automating via Apex).  Furthermore, the [releases page's](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils/releases) description of version 32.0.27 highlights the feature ability to "*create a file listener to automatically upload files after they are saved in a directory*."

So I decided to give it a try, but I cannot uncover any such feature; the ability to ultimately use the tool to automate csv uploads into Einstein Analytics.

Here's how it works:

1. Download the tool.
2. Launch the tool in a console and log into salesforce.

[image]

3. Then you're presented with the following EA options, each with it's own set of additional prompts when selected.

[image]

Unless I've missed something, none of these options uncovers what the tool "advertises" (by the way, option 1 - to load a csv - only let's you do so at that time).

Has anyone used this tool before and verified the claim that it can be used to automate csv uploads?  If so, what did you do to make that work?

Or do you know of another (free) way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the utility's [repository](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils), I missed that you can alternatively launch a UI with this command:

```
java -jar datasetutils-32.0.0.jar --server true
```

Once I did, I discovered the *listener* option there.  It's only available in the UI and the repository doesn't specify that.